# Why methods body is 'Bogus local variable signature' after applying Anti-tampering by ConfuserEx?

Tags: .net, obfuscation

I've craeted a simple app to test anti-tampering of ConfuserEx. After applying just anti-tampering, the method's body I'm interested in (defines a couple of variables and returns the result of applying an arithmetic operations on them) in IL is shown as

```
// Code size       -1646031153 (0x9de38ecf)
.maxstack  36481
```

******** ERROR: Bogus local variable signature (0x1A2262B0) ***********

Why is that? What are my options on how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anti-tampering in ConfuserEx replaces methods bodies with zero bytes. The actual method bodies are encrypted and stored in a different place within the assembly.